# How to mount or install Camunda for PHP?

Tags: php, camunda

I need your help to learn how to install Camunda BPM for PHP.

Now go to the official page and download the sdk but I do not understand if I should put those files in my project or follow the other alternative that says on the page. If someone has already done so, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sry, it is obvious that you need more about infrastructure of Camunda. Camunda is written in Java, so you cannot run it within a PHP environment (like Apache with PHP mod). What you can do is, run Camunda with the tomcat installation and then implement REST calls to the Camunda REST engine.

Maybe this is also interesting for you:
https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-php-sdk